# Why would insert or set for tkinter entry fields in python be extremely slow

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have an application that displays a grid of data and allows you to edit the date for each record.  Right now, I only have 5 records and each record has 3 entry fields for data points.

This is the relevant code, which is just populating the saved data into the entry fields when the screen loads:

```
start_time = time.time()
for student in sVars:
    scoresexist={"ps":False, "et":False, "v":False}
    for score in studentScores:
        if score['Name']==student['Student Name'] and score['week']==week and score['team']==team and score['section']==section and score['subject']==subject:
            if score['score'] != "":
                scoresexist[score['assignment']]=True
                myscore = score['score']
                setID = student[score['assignment']+"Entry"]
                setID.delete(0,END)
                setID.insert(0,myscore)
                setID.update()
    for key in scoresexist:
        if scoresexist[key]==False:
           student[key+"EntryID"].set("")
print("elapsed time is " + str(time.time() - start_time))
```

Once I started adding even a couple more records, the application started freezing.  Though trial and error, I eventually discovered the line that was taking so long was the

```
setID.insert(0,myscore)
```

If I comment out that line, or if I change that line to a get() instead of a set(), the elapsed time goes back to 0.0 seconds, regardless of the number of records I have tried.

When I have 4 or less records, the elapsed time for this code is around 0.5 seconds.
When I go up to 5 records, the elapsed time for this code is about 3 seconds
When I go up to 6 records, the elapsed time for this code is about 25 seconds
Once I get to 7 records, the application just freezes.
setID refers to the actual entry field
Before this trial I had that line as

```
setID.set(myscore)
```

and the setID referred to the textvariable of the entry field.  That line still made it just as slow.

Oh, also.. the reason there are 3 lines was during my hunting to find what was causing the delay.  Initially, I had

```
student[score['assignment']+"Entry"].set(score['score'])
```

I started separating things out into separate lines until I could see that the set (insert now) line was the one that was taking a long time.

Also, I started out without the

```
setID.update()
```

I added that and now I can see the fields pop in one at the time and know the computer is working, but it is still extremely slow to finish.  However, even without this line, it is still extremely slow.

Am I doing this wrong?  Or, is this just an issue that you can't use several entry fields without lagging?  Again, when I have 5 records, I have 15 entry fields.  When I have 7 records and the application freezes, I have 21 entry fields on the screen.

EDIT:

Here is an example of how the

```
#add to student dictionary
studentVars['psEntryID']=StringVar()
#create field for participation score
studentVars["psEntry"] = tk.Entry(newrow, textvariable=studentVars['psEntryID'])
studentVars["psEntry"].grid(row=0, column=currentcolumn, padx=(10,50))
#change to next column
currentcolumn = currentcolumn + 2



#add to student dictionary
studentVars['etEntryID']=StringVar()             
#create field for exit ticket score
studentVars["etEntry"]  = tk.Entry(newrow, textvariable=studentVars['etEntryID'])
studentVars["etEntry"] .grid(row=0, column=currentcolumn, padx=(10,50))
#change to next column
currentcolumn = currentcolumn + 2


#add to student dictionary
studentVars['vEntryID']=StringVar()   
#create field for vocabulary score
studentVars["vEntry"]  = tk.Entry(newrow, textvariable=studentVars['vEntryID'])
studentVars["vEntry"] .grid(row=0, column=currentcolumn, padx=(10,50))
```

and how it was traced

```
studentVars['psEntryID'].trace('w',lambda a, b, c, d=studentVars['psEntryID'], e=studentVars['Student Name'], f="ps": calculateStudent(a, b, d, d, e, f))
studentVars['etEntryID'].trace('w',lambda a, b, c, d=studentVars['etEntryID'], e=studentVars['Student Name'], f="et": calculateStudent(a, b, d, d, e, f))
studentVars['vEntryID'].trace('w',lambda a, b, c, d=studentVars['vEntryID'], e=studentVars['Student Name'], f="v": calculateStudent(a, b, d, d, e, f))
```

UPDATE:

I seem to have answered this myself.  The answer was apparently that I had the textvariable on trace to catch a change in the entry field.  So, when I loaded the saved data, everytime an entry field was updated, it must have been trying to do everything again over and over.  I removed the trace lines and instead used bind on

```
<FocusOut>
```

Right now, I have about 20 records and it's still loading the entire table in about 0.11 seconds.

Comment: can you add a summary example of your data structures sVars and studentScores

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show how you instantiated the `tk.Entry(...`,  e.g. did you bind the entry widget to a `StringVar` or any `callbacks`. `setID` is `type` of ?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. We can't run the code you posted because it includes objects that we have no way of knowing what they are.

Comment: added the part with the trace and setting up the variables

Comment: also, remember that the part where I assign the value to myscore and the part where i assign the value to setID doesn't lag at all.  If I only comment out the insert line, it runs at lightening speed.

Comment: WAIT!!!  This is when the program opens and loads.  Does this have something to do with the fact that the textvariable is traced instead of the object bound....and so WHILE I'm updating with the saved information it's also trying to reupdate again the whole time?  If so, how is that fixed, by only binding to FocusOut and not tracing?